# Passing current date over $http.post method angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to send curent date to my restapi so I can work with it. I'm assigning and passing parameters over `$http.post` method like this:

```
   (function() {
      var app;

      app = angular.module('vinclucms.sales');

      app.controller('FilterContactsListCtrl', [
        '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
          var nextContactListUpdateFailed, nextContactListUpdateSuccess;
          $scope.selectDate = null;
          $scope.doAction = function() {
            var data;
            data = {
              date: $scope.selectDate
            };
            return $http.post("/sales/lead_contact/", data).then(nextContactListUpdateSuccess, nextContactListUpdateFailed);
          };
          nextContactListUpdateSuccess = function() {
            return ClientNotifications.showNotification("Success", "Contact Leads list page was updated", "success");
          };
          return nextContactListUpdateFailed = function() {
            return ClientNotifications.showNotification("Alert", "Failed to update contact leads list page", "alert");
          };
        }
      ]);

    }).call(this);
```

Currently is set to `null` and I'm having problem with that in the rest it's returning `None` when I debug my view, question is How can I pass current date over `$http.post` method?

Date time picker field which I'm using to select date

```
<div class="flex-grid"
          ng-controller="FilterContactsListCtrl">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell size-p20 padding10">
                <label>Select Date: *</label>
                <div class="full-size">
                    <div class="input-control text" data-other-days="true"
                         data-week-start="1"
                         data-role="datepicker" date-format="mmmm d, yyyy">
                        <input type="text" ng-model="selectDate" ng-change="doAction()"/>
                        <button class="button">
                            <span class="mif-calendar"></span></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Where is it set to `null`? In your `/sales/lead_contact/` endpoint method? Could you provide code for that method as well?

Comment: well everything else is happening inside a `djangorestframework` view, so I didn't want to confuse, I was interested in this part of the pure angular code, I will try adding a filter, but if you have another suggestion, I'm opened to hear it @eminlala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to do date conversion, can you try as like below,

```
var data;
data = {
    date: $filter('date')(new Date($scope.selectDate), 'MM/dd/yyyy', 'US')
};
```

In case of current date:

```
var data;
data = {
    date: $filter('date')(new Date(), 'MM/dd/yyyy', 'US')
};
```

> **Note:** Please inject ***$filter*** into your controller